# How to use a button in HTML/JS to copy to the Clipboard the href link from an Anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, button, href, clipboard

I have an html file with a table collecting in every row several web links (url), and in the same table I would like to have a button for every row, that copies to the Clipboard the link of that row (embedded as 'href' in an anchor tag), giving to the user a feedback popup.

I've tried in several ways but it seems that most of the available examples show how to achieve that just for input fields, moreover with hard-coded functions that do not receive as a parameter the reference id for the text to be copied.

Any ideas?

-UPDATE-
I solved my problem thanks to the suggestion of Maassander.
Unfortunately the suggested thread was not specific enough for my issue:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that thread didn't exactly served my purpose. I needed specifically to copy href contents from many rows of one html table, using buttons, and Maassander's answers definitely solved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic version of this would look something like this I guess:

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  var button = rows[i].querySelector('button');
  
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var link = e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('a');
    var tempText = document.createElement('textarea');
    tempText.value = link.href;
    document.body.appendChild(tempText);
    tempText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(tempText);
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></td>
    <td><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a></td>
    <td><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maassander, it seems exactly what I was looking for and in your snippet it works like a charm. Sorry for my ignorance on the topic, but I would I embed the necessary javascript code in my html file? I've tried using the <script> tag but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Thorh73, the first part of my answer is what you would put within <script></script> tags. Can you edit your question and place your current code there? That would make it easier to spot where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot... my mistake was putting the script part BEFORE the html code for the table: it that situation the script code is not able to identify the buttons. When I moved the script part AFTER the code for the table, everything worked as expected! Thanks a lot!